# calculation of work

Tags: calculus

How much work is required to lift a $1500$ kg satellite to an altitude of $4.5 \times 10^6$ m above the surface of the earth?

The gravitational force is $F=\frac{GMm}{r^2}$, where $M$ is the mass of the earth, $m$ is the mass of the satellite, and $r$ is the distance between them. The radius of the earth is $6.4 \times 10^6$ m, its mass is $6 \times 10^{24}$ kg, and in these units the gravitational constant, $G$, is $6.67 \times 10^{-11} \text{N} \text{m}^2/\text{kg}^2$.

Work =   ? Joules

when i worked it out i got 14655.76 J which is the incorrect answer. i treated the weight of the satellite dish as 'm'  in the equation  GMmT/R(R+T) to equate the work in joules.

Comment: This should be on Physics.SE, right?

Comment: its a calculus question though???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work $W$ is defined in general as

$$ W = \int_{\Gamma} F(r) dr$$

where $F(r)$ is the force which depends on the distance, and $\Gamma$ is the trajectory of the mass.
In our case, $\Gamma = [R ~~~ R+T]$, where $R$ is the radius of heart and $T$ is the altitude at which satellite must arrive, while the force is the gravitational one, then:

$$W = \int_{R}^{R+T} \frac{GMm}{r^2}dr = $$
$$ = \frac{GMm}{R} - \frac{GMm}{R+T} = \frac{GMmT}{R(R+T)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Work is defined as the integral of Force with respect to distance.

So we have

$\large W=\int_{path} F\cdot dr=\int_{r=h_1}^{r=h_2}\frac{GMm}{r^2}dr=[-\frac{GMm}{r}]_{r=h_1}^{r=h_2}=-\frac{GMm}{h_2}+\frac{GMm}{h_1}$

where $h_1$ is the initial height of the satellite in metres (the radius of the Earth) and $h_2$ is the final height of the satellite in metres (the radius of the Earth plus the satellite altitude), $M$ is the mass of the earth, $m$ is the mass of the satellite, and $G$ is the Gravitational Constant.

Note that the result will be positive, as $h_1<h_2$, which means that work will be expended to move the satellite to its altitude.

I leave the rest for you to do - ensure that the units are metres for distance and kilograms for mass, and the units of the result will be Joules.

Comment: You are welcome, @user132138.